# Function only available for parameter property

Tags: ios, swift, syntax, properties, where-clause

Is it possible to have a function available only when the property of a parameter meets a certain condition? For example, by using the where keyword? I gave an example of the idea below.

```
struct ASN1 {

    enum Types: UInt8 {
        case constructed
        case primitive
    }

    class Tag {
        let type: Types
    }

    class Encoder {

        func enter(tag: ASN1.Tag) where tag.type == .constructed {
            // Function only available when tag property type is .constructed
        }

    }
}
```